# CEFsharp browser injecting jquery

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I am trying to inject jquery into CEFsharp browser but it didn't work don't know why !

here is snippet code of what I tried. is there any other way to load jquery to the loaded page in CEFsharp browser

```
 string query = "(function () {
        // more or less stolen form jquery core and adapted by paul irish
        function getScript(url, success) {
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = url;
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
                done = false;
            // Attach handlers for all browsers
            script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (!done && (!this.readyState
                    || this.readyState == 'loaded'
                    || this.readyState == 'complete')) {
                    done = true;
                    success();
                    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
                    head.removeChild(script);
                }
            };
            head.appendChild(script);
        }
        getScript('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js', function () {
            if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
                console.log('Sorry, but jQuery wasn\'t able to load');
            } else {
                console.log('This page is now jQuerified with v' + $.fn.jquery);

                $(document).ready(function () {
                    alert(1);
                    //here you can write your jquery code
                });
            }
        });
    })();";

     LoginWebbrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync(query);
```

Comment: Try `//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js` instead.

Comment: tried to do so but it didn't work:



   LoginWebbrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync("https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js");
                    await LoginWebbrowser.EvaluateScriptAsync("https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js");

Comment: You can open `DevTools`, see if there are any errors. Use http://cefsharp.github.io/api/67.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensions_ShowDevTools_1.htm

Comment: $ is not defined !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cefsharp winforms: Inject jquery into page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36999063/cefsharp-winforms-inject-jquery-into-page)

Answer (score 0):

```
string jq = @"var scr = window.document.createElement('script');
scr.type = 'text/javascript';
scr.src = 'https://apps.bdimg.com/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js';
var head = window.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
head.appendChild(scr);"
LoginWebbrowser.EvaluateScriptAsync(jq);
```