# Need to jQuerify CEF browser in winforms C# solution

Tags: c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

Trying to jQuerify CEF browser in winform solution but the script is not executing, tried many methods but still it didn't work.

I am executing the script in the LoadingStateChanged  .. already installed cefsharp from Nuget packages solution !

if there is another option better than CEFsharp please recommend !

```
       string script = @"(function () {
    // more or less stolen form jquery core and adapted by paul irish
    function getScript(url, success) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = url;
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
            done = false;
        // Attach handlers for all browsers
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (!done && (!this.readyState
                || this.readyState == 'loaded'
                || this.readyState == 'complete')) {
                done = true;
                success();
                script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
                head.removeChild(script);
            }
        };
        head.appendChild(script);
    }
    getScript('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js', function () {
        if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
            console.log('Sorry, but jQuery wasn\'t able to load');
        } else {
            console.log('This page is now jQuerified with v' + $.fn.jquery);

            $(document).ready(function () {
                alert(1);
                //here you can write your jquery code
            });
        }
    });
})();";


                    if (this.InvokeRequired)
                    {





                        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {

                            LoginchromeBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync(script);
                            LoginchromeBrowser.EvaluateScriptAsync(script).ContinueWith(x =>
                            {
                                var response = x.Result;

                                if (response.Success && response.Result != null)
                                {
                                    var startDate = response.Result;
                                    MessageBox.Show(response.Result.ToString());
                                    //startDate is the value of a HTML element.
                                }
                            });


                        });

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LoginchromeBrowser.EvaluateScriptAsync(script).ContinueWith(x =>
                        {
                            var response = x.Result;

                            if (response.Success && response.Result != null)
                            {
                                var startDate = response.Result;
                                MessageBox.Show(response.Result.ToString());
                                //startDate is the value of a HTML element.
                            }
                        });



                    }
```

Comment: It looks like you've hacked the example from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36999063/cefsharp-winforms-inject-jquery-into-page without really spending time to understand what's going on. Firstly your executing a piece of `JS` that doesn't return a result, it's not clear how `startDate` is relevant here? There is no need to execute `JS` on the `UI` thread, you only need to execute the continuation on the `UI` thread to show your message box. Make sure you are executing the script when args.IsLoading = false`, you cannot execute scripts when the page is loading.

Comment: Be helpful if you fixed the code formatting also, and included what your actually trying to do, it appears your are attempting to do more then just load `jQuery`.